# Communicate between VB.NET applications across a LAN and WAN

Tags: vb.net

I'm looking into writing an application that will run on multiple machines on the network - I haven't started to write any code yet as I'm looking into options at the moment - I'll have each client inform the server of their presence, possibly by updating a SQL table that stores machine info and an "Offline / Online" status field...  unless you can think of a better way of doing this?

As well as the client running on each users PC on the network, there will be "operators" running a different application.

What I'd like to be able to do is have the operators send messages to clients, the client then receives this message and displays it in a notification window. The operators application will do a SQL query to get all online clients and then send the notification only to these machines.

I can do the SQL side of things, the part I have no idea how to do... how do I have the operator application send notifications to the clients once it has the list it needs to send to?

I'll need to be able to send two strings at once:-
- Notification Title (String & Date.Now to show when the message was sent)
- Notification Message (multiline - no more than 5 lines)

Any help on how to have a vb.net application read two text boxes and send the contents to a remote vb.net application that can then assign those values to variables to be used and passed to a notification popup (I already have the popups working) would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.
Merick.

Comment: I think I would have the operator write to SQL and the clients periodically poll the table for any new notifications. But as it is, this question isn't quite fit for SO. You should get going and come back when you're stumped - after researching of course :)

Comment: Hi @retailcoder,  Over-complication strikes again! Writing to SQL and polling the table will be much easier!  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how complicated and exciting you want to make this task, you may want to explorer the [pub/sub](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tomholl/archive/2008/05/17/building-a-pub-sub-message-bus-with-wcf-and-msmq.aspx) model and handle communication using WCF and some message queue (like MSMQ, Tibco, ActiveMQ, etc)